# automate a page which was generate some fields by using javascript

Tags: java, htmlunit

i am  facing problem in automation, using Htmlunit , a page is generate some value by  using javascript , the values a available in inspact element but not in page source code . 
please give me some suggestion . 
i  am sharing the url where i m facing problem .
**http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx** or **http://blacklistalert.org/**
here i put a ipaddress for checking that  is blacklisted or not but unable to automate result,

Answer (score 0):

d.findElement(By.xpath("//div//div//div//input[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtToolInput']")).sendKeys("12.2.2.5");d.findElement(By.xpath("//div//div//div//input[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAction']")).click();